# Display product images DYNAMICALLY in Woocommerce product gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce shop with hundreds of items with unique images.  Some of these items could re-use the same "common" image, and I already have a script for calling the common images reliably.  However, I do not know how to include the common image in the product page gallery without modifying the postmeta table record.  By calling the update_post_meta function, I can insert the image ID and have it show up in the gallery.  But doing it this way is not really a good approach because if I ever have to change the common image down the road, then it will start to become a pain in the butt.  I'd much rather keep the script dynamic, and only load the common images as the product page generates the PHP.  In other words, I do not want any table records being updated in the WP tables just to display common images.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm convinced there is a way to do this by modifying my theme files, however, I wanted to know if there was already a built-in Wordpress action/filter that allows images to be inserted dynamically without modifying the theme files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filter should work

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_gallery_image_ids', 'add_dynamic_gallery_images', 10, 2);

function add_dynamic_gallery_images($ids, $product){
  $ids[] = 100; //image ID to add
  return $ids;
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, and I believe it will work perfectly  if I can get the right filter.  but as i'm testing it, it doesn't seem to do anything.  I'm trying to find information about 'woocommerce_get_product_gallery_image_ids' and I couldn't find anything

Comment: I also tried 'get_gallery_image_ids' which has some documentation but it also did not do anything.

Comment: Searched through the valid hooks in this list, and none seem to target this case specifically.  Maybe I'm not looking in the right place: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html

Comment: There's a `get_prop` filter in `woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-data.php#L821`, just need to figure out how to use it correctly

Comment: I have updated it and tested, it works now.

Comment: whoa.  i read about get_prop and how it works, and then figured it out.  you taught me two new things today.  thank you